# Print HTML table in foreach loop

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch data in table row. The problem is I am getting different output. All columns are printed in one column.

```
foreach ($user1 as $key => $value) {
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
    $timing= date('H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    $error_p = implode(' ', $product[0])."<br>";
    $error_d = implode(' ', $checked[0])."<br>";
    $html = '<table border="1">';
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td bgcolor='#D0D0FF'>$error_p</td>";
    $html .= "<td bgcolor='#D0D0FF'>$error_d</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
    $html .= "</table>";
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
}
```

Output is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you create a new table element for every user. so put the table outside of your foreach loop so that it looks something like this:

```
   $html='<table border="1">';
   foreach ($user1 as $key =>$value) {
      $date1 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
      $timing= date('H:i:s',strtotime($date));
      $error_p = implode(' ', $product[0]);
      $error_d = implode(' ', $checked[0]);
      $html .= "<tr>";
      $html .= "<td bgcolor='#D0D0FF'>$error_p</td>";
      $html .= "<td bgcolor='#D0D0FF'>$error_d</td>";
      $html .= "</tr>";
    }
    $html.="</table>";
    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: chris2top@after using your solution get same result

Comment: chris2top@ I solved this  I have to remove this  <br> tag from my variable .please upadte your answer without <br> .I want to accept your answer